# How can i change email template outer background color magento 2.4.1

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates

I want to change outer background color of email template.So let me know how can i change background color. In which file i can change background color

screen-shot : https://www.screencast.com/t/9F2EakX4RZ

Thanks

Comment: Did you take the picture from preview template? Did you try viewing the email from real email?

Comment: @Jimmy preview which is in screen-shot that is from gmail's email screen-shot